# SQL Server AFTER UPDATE trigger to update another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have tables `master_product` and `transactions`.

If I change `productID` in the `master_product` table, I want to update the  `ProductID` column in the `transactions` table.

I want to use a trigger, but I don't know how to write it. Can you please help me write the trigger?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please show us the **table structures** of those two tables? How are those two tables linked, e.g. what is / are the common column(s) ?`

Comment: master_product have 3 columns: productID, productName, Categories (the productID is the primary key), 
transactions have 3 columns: ID, productID, Qty (ID is the primary key, and the productID is linked to masterproduct)

Comment: It usually is not necessary that update primary key field. Why do you need it?

Comment: yes it is not necessary to update the primary key, but what i want is if the primary key (productID) updated by mistakes, the entire product_id in transactions is updated as well

Comment: @YohanWijayanto you can take a look here [Trigger](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4024/sql-server-trigger-after-update-for-a-specific-value/)

Comment: It's a really really horribly bad idea to update the primary key of any table - ever. In this particular case, in an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, you need to be able to *connect* the old and new rows together - so that you can update the second table - select those rows matching the **old** value, and set the column to the **new** value.

But since you're updating the **primary key** of `master_product`, you **cannot** connect the old and new values - since they don't have anything in common anymore, since you've changed the primary key ..... once more: this is a **horribly bad idea**!

Comment: thank you @marc_s, i think your answer is logic, and maybe locking the productID is the easiest way to prevent mistakenly update productID

Comment: You can't update productID, You would get a foreign key constraint error.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to change your foreign key constraint and add "**ON UPDATE CASCADE**" ?

SQL Server will manage everything.

```
alter table Categories drop constraint your_constraint_name
go
alter table Categories add constraint your_constraint_name
foreign key (productID) references master_product (productID) on update cascade on delete no action
```